# Why does Vuejs not pickup changes when watching a momentjs?

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

Per this question here, [Vuejs: Computed property not updating the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144491/vuejs-computed-property-not-updating-the-view/51144644#51144644), I am watching for changes to instances of moment.js, and the view does not update.

Here's an excerpt from the original code that does not work:

```
set(value) {
    this.paidFinish = this.paidFinish.hour(value);
}
```

Here's what I did to fix it:

```
set(value) {
    this.paidFinish = this.paidFinish.clone().hour(value);
}
```

Why does Vuejs not detect the changes?  The object is being accessed via `this`, and the property `paidFinish` is present in the initial data.  (Initially it is set to `''`, but when the component is mounted it is set to a moment.)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same problem.

Turns out that [the moment object mutates and always returns the same object](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/), so Vue cannot add reactivity to it (see [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) for some clarification about this).

Workaround is either to use [frozen-moment](https://github.com/WhoopInc/frozen-moment) library or creating an interval in your component:

```
data () {
  return {
    time: ''
  }
},
beforeMount () {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.time = moment().format('HH:mm:ss')
  }, 1000)
}
```

---

Or...

> Use [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) that is immutable